# Red and yellow wires to aftermarket stereo system have no power

Tags: audio, electronics

I have a 2001 Chevy Silverado diesel 2500 4x4.  I took my old stereo out which had power to it, and I installed my new stereo.  Now the red and yellow wires have no power! (They did before.)  I checked all the fuses, and they all seem to be good.

---

I've checked everything all I did was unplug the old stereo n plug the new one in and nothing now the red n yellow wire have to power

Comment: Is there an inline fuse? Or poor connection? Have you checked the switch?

Answer (score 1):

If you used an adaptor harness from original car to radio, maybe the configuration is wrong. 
Have you checked with a multimeter to see if any of the other wires have power ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same wires to provide power then there are very few possibilities.

The most likely, as mentioned in comments, is that you blew a fuse while changing things over. And this is also the best possible, as it's an easy fix.

Next things to check would be any switches (is one of the wires switched with the ignition?) or even wires that may have been dislodged or broken.

If you have a continuity checker and volt meter you should check all the wiring that goes to your audio system.

Answer (score 0):

Unplug the new stereo, and test the wire coming from the car's wiring for 12v.

If there's power at the connector, then the new wiring or head unit is defective.

If, on the other hand, there isn't power, then something is now awry at the car end: a fuse (perhaps hidden), a physical wiring break or fault, or the other end of the wire has come loose when you were manipulating it to make the new connection.